# Application doesn't redirect to next page

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have created one small app through meteor. When I run the app on local host it works well. But when I access that app from remote laptop or desktop the app doesn't redirect to next pages of app.

I have used the command to redirect:

```
$('#right2').html(Meteor.ui.chunk(Template.MessageInboxDetails));
```

Will you please give some suggestion?

Comment: What is the code you are using to do the redirect? Any chance there is a 'localhost' or something like that hidden in there?

Answer (score 1):

I think `ui.chunk` is deprecated now.

I don't typically like to do page routing by stuffing template into the dom.

Consider this:

```
{{{display_page}}}

Template.whatever.display_page = function() {
    return Template[Session.get("current_page_id")]()
}
```

Now all you have to do is set session  on your event to route to the new page